# centering inline-block elements when flexbox and classic techniques don't work

Tags: html, css, centering

In the page [here: https://irfan.io](https://irfan.io)

I have tried centring the smaller circles every-way I can think of and they either don't get centred or the centring is not responsive-- meaning it fails when the viewport is changed.

They are all of class .small and they are children of #main.

I have tried flexbox:

```
#main{
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
}
.small{
    display:flex;
}
```

I have tried giving wrapping the .small elements in a container and giving that a fixed width and centring with -0.5 of the width:

```
#smallContainer{
    width:500px;
    margin-left:-250px;
    position:relative;
    left:50%;
}
```

I also figured since they were inline-block elements I could use `text-align:center;` on the .small element, but that didn't work.

```
#small{
   text-align:center;
}
```

I can't seem to figure out how to centre 3 small circles so that the middle one is in the vertical-middle like the bigger circle ( .big ), which I centred using the 2nd technique.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this:

**DEMO:**

```css
#main{
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
    position:relative;
}
.small{
    display:flex;.
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
#smallContainer{
    margin-left:0 auto;
    position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div id="smallContainer">
        <div class="small">
            text
        </div>       

        <div class="small">
            text
        </div>       

        <div class="small">
            text
        </div>       
    </div>
</div>
```

[fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/5Lbkars6/6/)

What i did is simple.. just make #main and #smallContainer position relative, remove the left and width from #smallContainer to make it expand only according to its children, then put margin:0 auto; to #smallContainer. This way even if the viewport change you're sure the .small div's are centered.

**EDIT**

I updated the fiddle, I just removed the display:inline-block; from .small in css.

Dont forget to mark this as answer if it gives you what you need my friend :)

Comment: Thank you! it worked, but now it is just a column of all 3 smaller circles vertically. I need the 3 circles to be in one horizontal line.

Comment: just remove display:inline-block; from .small

Comment: yup-- I did it with inline-flex and it works perfectly now! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have a mistake. Your inline-block elements has a left of 50% (even you will center, there are a 50% more to the right).

You can solve like this:

```
#smallContainer { text-align: center; }
.small { left: 0; }
```

Comment: I just tried it in developer tools. When I give the container the `text-align:center;` and remove the 50% left, It changes it, but it is not centred.

Comment: You have a width in the `body` of 1332 pixels, I don't know why, but it is bigger than my screen. Your total content has more that 100% of the width. your problem seems to be it. I can't see what produces it.